# Word for prayer responses

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word for the responses which people utter during prayer recitals or general "praise the lord" sort of speeches (not in sermons). Let me try elucidating this via an example:

```
Priest: "blah blah blah"
Random Person: "amen"
Priest: "blah blah blah"
Random Person: "ooo, praise the lord"
Priest: "blah blah blah"
Random Person: some random quote praising the lord
```

The best example would be the stuff you see in movies, typically portrayed in African-American churches. I'm sure there's a word for it. Also, forgive me if the meaning is not clear.

Comment: You're talking about the formalized ones and not random "amen"s, right?  E.g. the book of liturgy (for whatever religion) will say that the priest says "blah blah blah" and the people say "amen".  Correct?

Comment: @Monica no i'm talking about the random ones. and the word need not be amen, just some expression of praise or support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [litany](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/litany?s=t).

Comment: yeah, actually, i think this was the word.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, this pattern is called *[call and response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_and_response)*.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. I *believe* that "call and response" is also more generally accepted *outside* of African-American religious tradition despite what the Wikipedia article implies.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure the word is simply "response". I have seen in prayer books:

> Congregation responds: "Amen"

Comment: It is a very common word in most of the religions.

Answer (score 3):

These might be 'ejaculations' (sniggering down in back, please). Here is the catholic culture org explanation:
http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33288

I recall them being explained as something like your random persons in the example might say, though at any time, not in a 'call and response' setting.

For instance, Wikipedia has this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejaculation_(grammar)

Answer (score 1):

try [responsory or respond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsorial)

> The most general definition of a responsory is any psalm, canticle, or
>   other sacred musical work sung responsorially, that is, with a cantor
>   or small group singing verses while the whole choir or congregation
>   respond with a refrain. However, this article focuses on those chants
>   of the western Christian tradition that have traditionally been
>   designated by the term **responsory**.